# Asterisk qualify log

Tags: logging, asterisk

I use qualify=15000 in mysip.conf. Sometimes in log file i saw like this line.

```
chan_sip.c: Peer '313' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 5
chan_sip.c: Peer '313' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 7
```

whats does it menas 5 or 7 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is value in MS from the moment when asterisk sends OPTIONS packet to the moment it receives.

i.e it is like ping value via SIP.

Current values can be checked using

```
asterisk -rx "sip show peers"
```

Comment: If sip is unreachable how Asterisk can receive packet from it?

Comment: If it unreachable, that mean ping was more then qualify value. Value of "yes" is 2000, you also can put any value you think acceptable. Message you quoted show PREVOUS value of ping, before it become UNRECHABLE.